# Why does this code work without a mutex?

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, pthreads

I am trying to learn how locks work in multi-threading. When I execute the following code without lock, it worked fine even though the variable sum is declared as a global variable and multiple threads are updating it. Could anyone please explain why here threads are working perfectly fine on a shared variable without locks?

Here is the code:

```
    #include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NTHREADS      100
#define ARRAYSIZE   1000000
#define ITERATIONS   ARRAYSIZE / NTHREADS

double  sum=0.0, a[ARRAYSIZE];
pthread_mutex_t sum_mutex;


void *do_work(void *tid) 
{
  int i, start, *mytid, end;
  double mysum=0.0;

  /* Initialize my part of the global array and keep local sum */
  mytid = (int *) tid;
  start = (*mytid * ITERATIONS);
  end = start + ITERATIONS;
  printf ("Thread %d doing iterations %d to %d\n",*mytid,start,end-1); 
  for (i=start; i < end ; i++) {
    a[i] = i * 1.0;
    mysum = mysum + a[i];
    }

  /* Lock the mutex and update the global sum, then exit */
  //pthread_mutex_lock (&sum_mutex);  //here I tried not to use locks
  sum = sum + mysum;
  //pthread_mutex_unlock (&sum_mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, start, tids[NTHREADS];
  pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  /* Pthreads setup: initialize mutex and explicitly create threads in a
     joinable state (for portability).  Pass each thread its loop offset */
  pthread_mutex_init(&sum_mutex, NULL);
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++) {
    tids[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, do_work, (void *) &tids[i]);
    }

  /* Wait for all threads to complete then print global sum */ 
  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  printf ("Done. Sum= %e \n", sum);

  sum=0.0;
  for (i=0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++){ 
  a[i] = i*1.0;
  sum = sum + a[i]; }
  printf("Check Sum= %e\n",sum);

  /* Clean up and exit */
  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&sum_mutex);
  pthread_exit (NULL);
}
```

With and without lock I got the same answer!

```
Done. Sum= 4.999995e+11 
Check Sum= 4.999995e+11
```

UPDATE: Change suggested by  user3386109

```
for (i=start; i < end ; i++) {
a[i] = i * 1.0;
//pthread_mutex_lock (&sum_mutex);
sum = sum + a[i];
 //pthread_mutex_lock (&sum_mutex); 
}
```

EFFECT :

```
    Done. Sum= 3.878172e+11 
   Check Sum= 4.999995e+11
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of concurrency. Race conditions are timing dependent. Sometimes it may "work" in that the right result is produced. But the code is still wrong because if you run it more times, with more threads or on different systems then some times it will fail. This is called non-deterministic behaviour.

Comment: Analogy: I built a space rocket and it blasted off successfully with and without a few of the screws in place. Does it mean those screws are not required? No, it means I was lucky and that space rocket can fail at any time.

Comment: Try it without the local variable `mysum`. Update the global `sum` in the `for` loop and see if that has any effect.

Comment: You might look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutexes are used to prevent race conditions which are undesirable situations when you have two or more threads accessing a shared resource.  Race conditions such as the one in your code happen when the shared variable `sum` is being accessed by multiple threads.  Sometimes the access to the shared variable will be interleaved in such a way that the result is incorrect and sometimes the result will be correct.

For example lets say you have two threads, thread A and thread B both adding 1 to a shared value, `sum`, which starts at 5.  If thread A reads `sum` and then thread B reads `sum` and then thread A writes a new value followed by thread B writing a new value you will can an incorrect result, 6 as opposed to 7.  However it is also possible than thread A reads and then writes a value (specifically 6) followed by thread B reading and writing a value (specifically 7) and then you get the correct result.  The point being that some interleavings of operations result in the correct value and some interleavings result in an incorrect value.  The job of the mutex is to force the interleaving to always be correct.